# SSMS Import/Export Wizard not loading

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Can't find anything about this anywhere else so figured I'd ask here:  The Import/Export Wizard for my SSMS is no longer loading.  I right click on the database -> Tasks -> Import Data as normal but then nothing happens.  No error/failure message or anything, the Wizard just never pops up.

The "Import Flat File" works fine, it's just the "Import Data" and "Export Data" options that are not working.

I was able to use this successfully last month (I have a single Excel file I import at the end of each month) and I have not done any updates so not sure what changed.

Any thoughts or direction on where I can go for troubleshooting tips?

Answer (score 0):

Try 64 bit SSMS Import/Export Wizard
Hope it will work.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLshW.png)